# In Washington state must a doctor report situations that happened in the past?

Tags: united-states, medical-ethics, legal

Are Washington state's mandated reporting requirements triggered if a doctor discovers that their adult patient had been abused in the past? What if there are no longer any 'protected populations' at risk (no children, no vulnerable adults/elderly,...)?
What if the patient talks exclusively in hypothetical terms?

Comment: Please forgive if this question is out of place in this stack exchange community. This medical-science  community seems to have quite a variety of posts. But, I am new to this entirely.

Comment: This question is outside the scope of Medical Sciences. It would possibly be appropriate on the Law exchange, but I'm not certain enough of that to migrate it. I would recommend that you read the help section on Law.SE and if your question can be adapted to that site, that's your best audience.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's a legal question, not medical.